# Как заменить повторяющийся текст на разные значения из массива?

Tags: php

Требуется замена повторяющегося элемента в тексте на разные значения из массива.
Например есть большая строка:

`$str = 'текст <a href="/">ссылк</a>, <a href="/">еще ссылк</a>траливали <a href="/">и еще ссылк</a>';`

есть массив:

```
$arr = array('</a><b>1</b>', '</a>2_', '</a>3ыа');
```

`нужно в $str заменить первое '</a>' на '</a><b>1</b>', второе'</a>' на '</a>2_', и третье '</a>' на '</a>3ыа' соотвественно`

количество искомых в $str всегда равно количеству элементов в массиве $arr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, такой метод:

```
$STRING  = '1</a>2</a>3</a>';
$ARRAY   = array('1', '2', '3');
echo preg_replace_callback('#</a>#is', function ($MATCHES) use(&$ARRAY) {
    return array_shift($ARRAY);
}, $STRING);
```

Answer (score 1):

Сперва находить контейнер `<a>...</a>`  далее - производить замену в найденном контейнере. Ну и после каждой замены перемещать курсор указателя массива с элементами для замены *(в данном примере - увеличивать счётчик ключа массива)*:

```
$str = 'текст <a href="/">ссылк</a>, <a href="/">еще ссылк</a>траливали <a href="/">и еще ссылк</a>';

$arr = ['</a><b>1</b>', '</a>2_', '</a>3ыа'];


echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~<a[^>]*>.+?</a>~',
    function($a)use($arr) {
        static $i = -1;
        if (isset($arr[++$i])) {
            return preg_replace('~</a>~', $arr[$i], $a[0]);
        }
    },
    $str
);
```

Результат до замены:

```
текст <a href="/">ссылк</a>, <a href="/">еще ссылк</a>траливали <a href="/">и еще ссылк</a>
```

Результат после замены:

```
текст <a href="/">ссылк</a><b>1</b>, <a href="/">еще ссылк</a>2_траливали <a href="/">и еще ссылк</a>3ыа
```